# Use filename as an indicator to process datetime columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I am reading 15 csv files into pandas dataframe. The columns that I want in final dataframe are spread across multiple csv files

Filename pattern for file 1 to file 8 - Med* (ex: Med1, Med2, Medtest, Medkill)

Sample data from file 1 to file 8 looks like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                   'start_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM'],'type':['O','I','O','O','I','O','I']})
```

Filename pattern for file 9 to file 12 - Adm* (ex: Adm1, Adm2, Admaasd, Admmed)

Sample data from file 9 to file 12 looks like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                        'start_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM'],
                        'end_date':['5/12/2013 09:27:00 AM',np.nan,'06/11/2014 08:00:00 AM',np.nan,'12/16/2011 10:00:00','10/18/2012 00:00:00',np.nan],
                        'type':['O','I','O','O','I','O','I']})
```

Filename pattern for file 13 to file 15 - cas* (ex: castest, caste22, caskill)

Sample data from file 13 to file 15 looks like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101],
                   'start_date':['5/2/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/03/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/01/2014 08:00:00 AM'],'dur':['3w','3m','2d']})
```

In my final dataframe, I expect the column names to be as shown below

```
person_ID, start_date, end_date
```

As you can see in `file 1 to 8` there is no `end_date` column. Because `end_date = start_date`. So we have to copy the `start_date` value to `end_date` column

Similarly in `file 13 to 15`, we don't have `end_date` column as well. But we can derive `end_date` by adding the `duration` column values to `start_date`.

I tried the below

```
pat_dir = ['Med*.csv','C:\\test\\Adm*.csv', 'C:\\test12\\test13\\cas*.csv']
files_grabbed = [] 
cols = ['person_id','start_date','end_date']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=",",low_memory=False).reindex(columns=cols) 
       for f in files_grabbed]
```

Though the above code creates `end_date` column in the final dataframe with `NA` (for files which didn't have this column in their raw files).

The problem is how can I recognize that the files with patterns require different way of processing end_dates

`Med*` - copy start_date values as end_date

`cas*` - add duration to start_date and store them in end_date column

Through my code, I created a final dataframe but lost on how to apply end_date logic to those files?

Is it possible to add those logic before creating final dataframe or during read operation?

Comment: `add duration to start_date` - there is duration column?

Comment: yes, in sample dataframe...`dur`

Comment: Answer was edited, can you test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` statemenet for test by filenames:

```
import os

#custom function for add values by duration
def func(x):

    if pd.isna(x['dur']):
        return x['start_date']

    elif x[1] == 'w':
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(weeks=x[0])
    elif x[1] == 'm':
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x[0])
    elif x[1] == 'd':
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=x[0])
    else:
        return x['start_date']
```

---

```
dfs = []
for f in files_grabbed:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    name = os.path.basename(f)
    if name.startswith('Med'):
        dfs.append(df.assign(end_date = df['start_date']))

    elif name.startswith('cas'):

        df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
        df[[0,1]] = df['dur'].str.extract('(\d+)(\D+)')
        df[0] = df[0].fillna(0).astype(int)
     
        df['end_date'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
        dfs.append(df)
    else:
        dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: @TheGreat - whats should be happen if Na in `Dur column` ?

Comment: @TheGreat - Super, glad can help. Test way for `cas`, if there is somrthig else like `m,d,w` is necessary modify function.

Comment: Hi one minor issue, I updated the code to be like below

Comment: `def f(x):
    if x[1].lower().startswith('w'):
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(weeks=x[0])
    if x[1].lower().startswith('m'):
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x[0])
    if x[1].lower().startswith('d'):
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=x[0])
    if x[1].lower().startswith('y'):
        return x['start_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=x[0])`

Comment: when I finally do this `df.update(df[[0,1]]).fillna(0).astype(int)`, i get an error which reads `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'`

Comment: @TheGreat - yop, it is good. need `year`s with `s` for add years, more info is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)

Comment: I already added `s` to `year` in my code. So, it is `years` only. but `NA` is causing the issue

Comment: @TheGreat - Is possible first test and e.g. return `x['start_date']` if NA? Like in edited answer?

Comment: I got this error `ValueError: ('Non-integer years and months are ambiguous and not currently supported.', 'occurred at index 0')` when I use edited answer

Comment: @TheGreat - hmm, so need `df[0] = df[0].fillna(0).astype(int)` ? I test `dur` for missing values, so I hope it should be working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231163/discussion-between-the-great-and-jezrael).